# How to make an UITableView look like a grouped table with rounded corners?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rounded-corners, cornerradius

In my app I'm targeting `iOS 9` and above, and I'd like a grouped `UITableView` to look like grouped tables did in previous iOS versions:

[image]

That is, with some left and right padding and rounded corners in cells.

For the padding, this is working:

In my custom `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 12))
}
```

Then in the `UIViewController` subclass that handles the table view:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
```

That works. But now for the rounded corners, I'm trying to do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Top corners
    let maskPathTop = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.contentView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
    let shapeLayerTop = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerTop.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
    shapeLayerTop.path = maskPathTop.cgPath

    //Bottom corners
    let maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.contentView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
    let shapeLayerBottom = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerBottom.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
    shapeLayerBottom.path = maskPathBottom.cgPath

    // All corners
    let maskPathAll = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.contentView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
    let shapeLayerAll = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerAll.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
    shapeLayerAll.path = maskPathAll.cgPath

    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        cell.contentView.layer.mask = shapeLayerAll
    } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.contentView.layer.mask = shapeLayerTop
    } else if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        cell.contentView.layer.mask = shapeLayerBottom
    }
}
```

But, for some reason, when I run the app only left corners (top and bottom) are displayed rounded.

However, if I instead try this in that same method:

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```

All corners are displayed rounded. But this is not a solution for me, because I need to display different rounded corners depending on the cells in each section.

Could somebody help me to achieve this?

Comment: `But this is not a solution for me, because I need to display different rounded corners depending on the cells in each section.`

why dont you just assign the wanted corner radius depending on the cell the way you want it in cellForRow?

Comment: @DavidSeek in that method happens the same

Comment: according to your description, it is likely that those shapeLayerTop and shapeLayerBottom are simply to wide, cut their size a bit and it should work.

Comment: @IvanIčin too wide? Since I need to round off the corners of the cell's `contentView`, I'm using `cell.contentView.bounds` there, is that not correct?

Comment: @IvanIčin I just tried with a frame with shorter width and I get the same result

Comment: @AppsDev, not that but let maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.contentView.bounds... try to make it smaller for 20.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find a solution?